# How to load custom MNIST dataset using pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, mnist

I am working on a task related to adversarial training and attacks in machine learning.
I am fairly new to python/ML stuff so please bear with me. I am using code from [this](https://github.com/as791/Adversarial-Example-Attack-and-Defense/blob/master/Adversarial_Example_(Attack_and_defense).ipynb) repo which is working fine.

What I want to do: I want to load custom adversarial MNIST dataset instead of simple MNIST dataset using pyTorch like they are doing here (*dataset = datasets.MNIST(root = './data', train=True, transform = transform, download=True)*). And on that data I want to run the training procedures like they are running now. Basically, I want to train the model on already created adversarial examples of the MNIST dataset.

What I've tried:
I've tried [this](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2022/01/21/building-custom-image-data-sets-in-pytorch-tutorial-with-code/), and it does gives a general idea on how to load a custom dataset using pytroch but I'm stuck on how I should apply this to my case.

My Questions:

1. How exactly should I approach this?
2. Can I get adversarial(fgsm,ifgsm or whatever) data of MNIST that I could use or I have to create those myself and then load it. If yes, then how?

Below is the relevant part of the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision import transforms,datasets


# In[2]:


np.random.seed(42)
torch.manual_seed(42)


# In[3]:


transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.0,), (1.0,))])
dataset = datasets.MNIST(root = './data', train=True, transform = transform, download=True)
train_set, val_set = torch.utils.data.random_split(dataset, [50000, 10000])
test_set = datasets.MNIST(root = './data', train=False, transform = transform, download=True)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_set,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_set,batch_size=1,shuffle=True)


# In[4]:


print("Training data:",len(train_loader),"Validation data:",len(val_loader),"Test data: ",len(test_loader))


# In[5]:


use_cuda=True
device = torch.device("cuda" if (use_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available()) else "cpu") 
# Full code link is attached.
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating creating Adversarial example :

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/adversarial_fgsm

I think the best way to implement training with adversarial network is to create adversarial data while training (see https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans/blob/master/tutorials/tf2/mnist_tutorial.py for an exemple).

Comment: Thanks for the sugesstion, but, I've already looked into the first link and it only makes adversarial examples. Does not train the network on it. I've also looked into the cleverhans library as well but, I can't seem to reuse it with my existing code.